# How do I remove the "back to safety" warning on my website using html?

Tags: html, http, https, github-pages

I've coded a website and want some people to review it. However, some people have been concerned because a "back to safety" warning pops up for them. I've already gotten an SSL certificate for my website using Let's Encrypt, but the default link is still http. I've tried using the following code in the header of my html:

`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=https://www.yourdomainname.com" />`

This was one of the ways some places online said I could redirect traffic to https, since I'm using GitHub pages and I'm not sure how to implement php or make a .htaccess file. There are two problems I have:

First of all, it does redirect people to the https version of the website, but the warning still shows up in the beginning, so my main problem isn't solved.

Second of all, when I use this code, the website refreshes over and over, and I don't think that's good for UX.

Can anybody help me make my website more comfortable for users?

EDIT:
[Here's my website if you would like a look at it.](https://teampolair.com)

Answer (score 0):

if your website has no SSL you cannot remove back to safety it is an indicator of your website security in terms of information gathering, better of get an SSL Security for your site.

Comment: Is Let's Encrypt not a free SSL provider? I used it and it works when the website is in https